# How many letter were changed in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Hello I am fairly new at programming,

I would like to know is there a function or a method that allows us to find out how many letters have been changed in a string..

example:

input:

```
"Cold"
```

output:

```
"Hold"
```

**Hence only 1 letter was changed**

or the example:

input:

```
"Deer"
```

output:

```
"Dial"
```

**Hence 3 letters were changed**

Comment: Do you have to account for missing/extra characters?

Comment: What you're looking for is called the levenshtein distance. I have seen a Python library and a Java library that can efficiently calculate it. You'll have to go find them as I don't have a quick reference for you.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.11.1 -- In practise though (*different use case*) I've found that calculating the levenshtein is slower than simpliying computing the diff using the Python Standard Library ``difflibb.get_closest_matches()`` function.

Answer (score 2):

I spoke too soon. First result googling:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

This should be able to measure the minimum number of changes needed to get from one string to another.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to consider character insertions or deletions, the problem is reduced to simply counting the number of characters that are different between the strings.

Since you're new to programming, a imperative-style program would be:

```
def differences(string1,string2):
    i=0
    different=0
    for i in range(len(string1)):
        if string1[i]!=string2[i]:
            different= different+1
    return different
```

something slightly more pythonic would be:

```
def differences(string1,string2):
    different=0
    for a,b in zip(string1,string2):
        if a!=b:
            different+= 1
    return different
```

or, if you want to go fully functional:

```
def differences(string1,string2):
    return sum(map(lambda (x,y):x!=y, zip(string1,string2)))
```

which, as @DSM suggested, is equivalent to the more readable generator expression:

```
def differences(string1,string2):
    return sum(x != y for x,y in zip(string1, string2))
```

Comment: I think the simplest idiomatic version would be `sum(x != y for x,y in zip(s1, s2))`.

Comment: @DSM I guess using a comprehension rather than mapping is more usual, and certainly more readable. Thanks for the suggestion, do you mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: Not at all!  Although it's technically a generator expression, not a comprehension, because no object (list or set) is being built.

Comment: @DSM you're right, of course. I never understood why python has list *comprehensions* and generator *expressions* - especially since the notion is that "list comprehensions", in many other languages, are lazily evaluated

Comment: @goncalopp I think you are right and it would be better to call them all some sort of "comprehension".  But generator expressions were added to Python at the same time generators were added, and use similar machinery.  List comprehensions had already been in Python for a while.  So the new thing was named based on its implementation details.  Python has list comprehensions, dictionary comprehensions, set comprehensions, and... generator expressions?  I wish they had just called them "comprehensions"; a generator expression is pretty much a list comprehension without the list part!  :-)

Comment: @steaha I was hoping they'd make list comprehensions lazy in python 3, since map is now lazy. Then we'd need no generator **expressions**! (and `list(<lazily-evaluated-expression>)` seems awfully easy to optimize)

Answer (score 2):

Use the itertools library as follows (Python 3.x)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def change_count(string1, string2):
    count = 0
    for i, (char1, char2) in enumerate(zip_longest(string1, string2)):
        if char1 != char2:
            count = count + 1
    return count        
string1 = input("Enter one string: ")
string2 = input("Enter another string: ")
changed = change_count(string1, string2)
print("Times changed: ", changed)
```

Comment: Oh yes, `itertools.izip_longest()` handles the case where one string is a different length from the other!  +1 for that.  But you are using `enumerate()` for no reason, and I suggest using `sum(ch0 != ch1 for ch0, ch1 in izip_longest(string1, string2))`

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to process strings of different length this way. Say you have "dial" and "redial": most people would say there were two changes, but this algorithm will happily say there are 6.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the difflib library, particularly then [ndiff](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) method. Note: this is kind of overkill for the required job, but it is really great for seeing the differences between two files (you can see which are new, which are changed, etc etc)

```
word1 = "Cold"
word2 = "Waldo"
i = 0
differences = difflib.ndiff(word1, word2)
for line in differences:
    if line[0] is not " ":
        i += 1
print(i)
```